# Cannot access class inside module: "Main.rb:2:in `<main>': uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm newbie in ruby language.

I just need to execute a program that is written in ruby.

I checked-out [this small project](https://github.com/quadule/colorscore). Then saw it contains a gemfile and performed the following steps:

```sh
# Fist installed what I believe is needed
sudo apt install ruby-full
sudo gem install bundler

cd colorscore
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Then as proposed on the `README.md` created a file with content:

```rb
include Colorscore
histogram = Histogram.new('test/fixtures/skydiver.jpg')

# This image is 78.8% #7a9ab5:
histogram.scores.first # => [0.7884625, RGB [#7a9ab5]]

# This image is closest to pure blue:
palette = Palette.from_hex(['ff0000', '00ff00', '0000ff'])
scores = palette.scores(histogram.scores, 1)
scores.first # => [0.16493763694876, RGB [#0000ff]]
```

and executed:

```sh
bundle exec ruby Main.rb
```

The error I get is:

> Main.rb:2:in `': uninitialized constant Histogram (NameError)

It seems like the `Main.rb` file reads the `Colorscore` module, but cannot access the `Histogram` class inside it.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**versions:**

```
ruby -v
# ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
bundle -v
# Bundler version 2.1.4
```

Comment: I've tried your steps and initially got `NameError (uninitialized constant Colorscore)`. I've added `require 'colorscore'` at the beginning of the file and now it runs (except it complains about `convert` command because I don't have ImageMagick installed locally)

Comment: If you want to use a gem, you'll need to specifically include the file in your program using the `require` keyword, as @Olkin has done. Perhaps you can give that a try, and write it up as an answer if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Olkin/@BobRodes comments I've solved the issue:

I had to add: `require 'colorscore'` at the top of `Main.rb`